# How to trace this? AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation' during makemigrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm getting a confusing error for the second time since yesterday. Last time I just flattened my whole migrations, but I've never actually found what caused the problem.

So this comes up when I try to makemigrations for my python project. Where should I look for errors? I have feeling it's not actually about the migrations, but rather about errors in views.py or models.py even though I absolutely don't understand why this influences db migration.

Anyway, none of theses errors points to code that I have written. It's all in Django. So how to find the error that causes that?

```
(testenv1) C:\Users\user\eclipse_workspace\test1\test1>python manage.py makemigrations --trace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 150, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
  File "C:\Python27\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 323, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self.unmigrated_apps))
  File "C:\Python27\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 409, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
  File "C:\Python27\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 92, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "C:\Python27\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 148, in state_forwards
    delay = not old_field.is_relation
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'

(testenv1) C:\Users\user\eclipse_workspace\test1\test1>
```

Here is my models.py. It's currently WIP:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
#from wheel.metadata import unique
from datetime import datetime
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    code = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey("Sender", default=0)
    client = models.ForeignKey("Client", null=True,blank=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    route = models.TextField(blank=True)
    km = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    milage_receipt = models.ForeignKey("MilageReceipt", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def date(self):
        return self.datetime.date()
    def status(self):
        try: 
            if self.receipt and self.milage_receipt:
                return "done"
            elif not self.receipt:
                return "new"
            elif not self.milage_receipt:
                return "ok"
        except Receipt.DoesNotExist:
            return "new"
        except MilageReceipt.DoesNotExist:
            return "processing"
        return str(self.receipt)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.duration == None:
            self.duration = 0
        if self.km == None:
            self.km = 0
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task_update', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.code


class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    handle = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    zip2 = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    city2 = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    default_vat = models.IntegerField(default=7)
    km_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.slug

class Sender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    website = models.URLField()
    tax_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    vat_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bank = models.ForeignKey("BankAccount")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug

class BankAccount(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    iban = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    holder = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ReceiptNumber(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class MyQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def delete(self):
        print self
        raise

class SingleDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return MyQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)  

class Receipt(models.Model):
    number = models.OneToOneField("ReceiptNumber", blank=True, related_name="receipt", null=True)
    vat = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    task = models.OneToOneField("Task", related_name="receipt")
    objects = SingleDeleteManager()
    def total(self):
        a = float(self.amount) * (self.vat / 100.0) + float(self.amount)
        return "%.2f" % round(a,2)
    def vat_amount(self):
        a = float(self.amount) * (self.vat / 100.0)
        return "%.2f" % round(a,2)

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if self.date == None:
            self.date = datetime.now()
        if self.amount == None:
            self.amount = 0  
        if self.vat == None:
            self.vat = self.task.client.default_vat
        super(Receipt, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        #if not hasattr(self, "number") or self.number == None:
        #    new_number = ReceiptNumber.objects.create()
        #    new_number.number = ReceiptNumber.objects.filter(Q(receipt__task__sender_id=self.sender.id) | Q(milage_receipt__task__sender_id=self.sender.id)).latest('id').number+1
        #    new_number.save()
        #    self.number = new_number 
        #    super(Receipt, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self,"number") and self.number.id:
            self.number.delete()
        return super(self.__class__, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('receipt_create_for_task', args=[str(self.task.id)])
    def __unicode__(self):
        try:
            return str(self.number) + ": " + self.task.code
        except Task.DoesNotExist:
            return "should be gone"

class ReceiptTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    vat = models.IntegerField()
    amount = models.FloatField()
    body = models.TextField()

class MilageReceipt(models.Model):
    number = models.OneToOneField("ReceiptNumber", null=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey("Sender")
    client = models.ForeignKey("Client")
```

It's Version 1.11!

Comment: Can you show your models.py?

Comment: `none of theses errors points to code that I have written. It's all in Django` I like Django a lot, but this does happen quite a bit.

Comment: Yes, I added it. But it's super long! But because there is this weird error I don't know what to look for. How would you approach this?

Comment: What version of Django is this?

Comment: It's Version 1.11!

Comment: Migration errors typically occur when you made some changes to your models since a previous migration and it is trying to reference something that is no longer there. If you rename your migrations folder to something like `migrations_old` and run makemigrations again, do you still have errors?

Comment: FYI, that error has something to do with a removed field. That last frame of the traceback is from the `RemoveField` class. That may help narrow things down. Also, you can set verbosity on the `makemigrations` command with `-v 3`.

Comment: I just quick checked your models in Django 1.9 with Python 2.7 and migration was ok but still it is another version. Try to remove/rename old migrations and try it again. If not ok, I would try to comment out all models and try to enable one model (or model fields) at time and try.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was looking for ages, but then your comments made me check all the migrations by hand it turned out, that I am using the eclipse git in some wrong way. it hadn't noticed the deleted migrations and so everything was off. Still it would have been easier if Django had jus told me which migration isn't working. How can I mark this question as solved? Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Hello Jason! How about selecting an answer to your question? :-D

Answer (score 21):

I found an extremely useful way of debugging this on [this ticket on Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28489) by Radek.

If you feel brave, you can edit the `state_forwards()` method on `django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py` adding a debug print on the first line.

```
def state_forwards(self, app_label, state):
    # THIS IS THE LINE TO ADD
    print app_label + " " + self.model_name_lower + " " + self.name
    # END OF THE LINE TO ADD
    new_fields = []
    old_field = None
    for name, instance in state.models[app_label, self.model_name_lower].fields:
        if name != self.name:
            new_fields.append((name, instance))
        else:
            old_field = instance
    state.models[app_label, self.model_name_lower].fields = new_fields
    # Delay rendering of relationships if it's not a relational field
    delay = not old_field.is_relation
    state.reload_model(app_label, self.model_name_lower, delay=delay)
```

Then run again `./manage.py makemigrations`. Before crashing, you should see the name of the model that is making your migration fail.

Notice on the example below that the last model to be processed before crashing is `adsummary` on the `core` app, more specifically the  `account` field. By the way, after finding this I just searched for `adsummary` on the `migrations` folder on the `core` app, then found out that there was a command for removing this column in one of the migration files, though the column wasn't on the database anymore, deleted this command and `makemigrations` started working again.

```
Felipes-MacBook-Air:backend felipe$ ./manage.py makemigrations -v 3
contenttypes contenttype name
core adsummary account
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 150, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 323, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self.unmigrated_apps))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 409, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 92, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 149, in state_forwards
    delay = not old_field.is_relation
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'
```

Comment: This is useful debugging information. If you are going to add a `print()` statement to `fields.py`, it helps to add it to all the `state_forwards` functions - in all of the `AlterField`, `RenameField`, `AddField`, and `RemoveField` classes.

Comment: @Felipe Glad someone found that Django ticket of mine useful - I lost all my hair on it and then I have created that ticket with Django community that there is a bug with Django - I see that there are still issues with it. It is so annoying but that was happening during upgrade of lower version of Django to 1.11 in Django 2.0 - have not seen anything like it - was just doing it now for 1 client, the older upgrade... Thank you for posting it on overflow.

Comment: this and @Wessi answer help me to found a solution to my problem, thanks

Comment: If you are using python 3.4+, you need to use this: ```print(app_label + " " + self.model_name_lower + " " + self.name)```

Comment: This worked for me with Django 2.2.8 and Python 3.7.3!

Answer (score 10):

The same thing happened to me. I think there's a bug in Django 1.11. I downgraded to Django 1.10.7 and ran my migrations without problems and re-upgraded to 1.11 again after that.
There is an  [open ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28073):

> EDIT: IT's indeed a bug and it's still there in Django 2.1.4
>
> Found a way to fix it:
>
> Open `/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py` and go to the line
>   indicated in the exception in the state_forwards method and change the
>   line `delay = not old_field.is_relation` for `delay = old_field is
>   None or not old_field.is_relation`
>
> Found the fix on Markus Holtermann answer on
>   https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28073:
>
> I'm not entirely sure how you got to that line `delay = not
>   old_field.is_relation` with `old_field` being `None` as this means
>   there's no field with that name in `state.models[app_label,
>   self.model_name_lower].fields`, but I think it's safe to go with
>   `delay = old_field is None or not old_field.is_relation`.

Answer (score 6):

As [FamousJameous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765732/how-to-trace-this-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-is-relati#comment74574040_43765732) says, the problem is on the `RemoveField` method, probably used on a migration. In my case, the problem came when I was trying to remove a field what was not the defined (ex: I tried to remove `field_id`, created by a relationship, but the definition, and the correct one is `field`).

Comment: That helped me. I deleted the field manually from db.

Answer (score 2):

The same migration error happened to me. In my case it was caused by the underlying MySQL table schema becoming out of sync to the model specification in models.py. Specifically, my table had a column left over from an earlier failed migration.

I fixed the problem by manually deleting the column in MySQL and making sure the table schema matched models.py. I deleted the failed migration that caused the error and then re-did the deleted migration anew. Because the underlying table and the models.py schema were now in sync before I ran the migration it went through smoothly.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure how to solve this problem, but I will write what worked for me:

Find function `state_forwards` ( I am using ubuntu) at following path:

```
"/home/aseem/venv/bt_pip/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py"
```

`bt_pip` is my pip virtual env name stored in folder `venv`.In above state_forwards func add following line:

```
print (app_label + " " + self.model_name_lower + " " + self.name + str(self.field))
```

This will show which app is causing the problem.

Now install  [django-reset-migrations](https://github.com/valdergallo/django-reset-migrations). Then in terminal run :

```
python manage.py reset_migrations app_name
```

It showed me some error, but after that when I tried `python manage.py makemigrations` it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was running multiple databases off the same migrations when I got this error. The migrations had gotten messed up from one database. To patch it, I manually edited an old migration to not be applied on a RemovalField on one of the databases.

```
if (settings.STATUS == '...'):
    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='...',
            name='...',
        ),
```

This is by far from an ideal solution, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers try to find the field responsible of the error but do not give a solution.
I give the solution that worked in my case where there was no code error

### Origin migrations state

python manage.py showmigrations app

```
[X] 0098_auto_20211112_1311
[X] 0099_auto_20211112_1011
[ ] 0100_auto_20220107_1709
[X] 0100_auto_20220105_1114
[X] 0101_auto_20220112_1203
```

### Fix : revert migrations + remove migrations file + new migrations generation

I have to remove the migration that prevent me to revert migration.

```
rm app/migrations/0100_auto_20220107_1709.py
```

Now, I can revert migrations to common ancestor :

```
python manage.py migrate app 0099
```

I can now remove bad files :

```
rm app/migrations/0101_auto_20220112_1203.py
rm app/migrations/0100_auto_20220105_1114.py
```

I run migrations generation :

```
python manage.py makemigrations app
```

The migration could be executed without any issues

```
python manage.py migrate
```

**Please, pay attention this solutions works only if the two migrations 0100 and 0101 have not been executed on production.**

If others developper could have executed these migrations, they should follow this procedure.