# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'as_sql'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a Django project. that's ok to makemigrations, but it's error when I migrate. Please give me some advise, I didn't find the same case "as_sql" in Google. Thank you.
This is error details.

```
 python manage.py migrate                                                                                                                  
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, appointments, auth, clinics, contenttypes, patients, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying clinics.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/mtcm/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/mtcm/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 290, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 131, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 163, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 251, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 38, in __exit__
    super().__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 157, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 177, in execute
    sql = str(sql)
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/ddl_references.py", line 220, in __str__
    return self.template % self.parts
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/ddl_references.py", line 252, in __str__
    sql, params = self.compiler.compile(self.expressions)
  File "/Users/frank/Documents/projects/drcheck/DjangoVenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 496, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'as_sql'
```

This is my models

```
class ClinicInfo(models.Model):
    name_cn = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Chinese Name'))
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('English Name'))
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Short Name'))
    address_cn = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('Chinese Address'))
    address_en = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('English Address'))
    telnum_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=_('1st Tel No.'))
    telnum_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name=_('2nd Tel No.'))
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Email'))
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Fax'))

    class meta:
        verbose_name = _('Clinic Information')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Clinic Information')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_cn


class DoctorArg(models.Model):
    weekday_list = (
        (0, _('Monday')),
        (1, _('Tuesday')),
        (2, _('Wednesday')),
        (3, _('Thursday')),
        (4, _('Friday')),
        (5, _('Saturday')),
        (6, _('Sunday'))
    )

    period_list = (
        ('full', _('Full Day')),
        ('am', _('AM')),
        ('pm', _('PM'))
    )

    clinic = models.ForeignKey(ClinicInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Clinic'))
    weekday = models.IntegerField(
        choices=weekday_list, verbose_name=_('Weekday'))
    period = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=period_list, default='full', verbose_name=_('Period'))
    '''
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(
        MyUser, limit_choices_to={'role': 'Doctor'},
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Doctor'))
    '''
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Doctor Arrangement')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Doctor Arrangements')
        # unique_together = [['weekday', 'period', 'doctor']]

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Doctor arrangements'
```

I didn't find the same case "as_sql" in Google.
I tried to trace this error according to this way [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765732/how-to-trace-this-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-is-relati/), but didn't get debug print.

Comment: Its hard to read the error from image. Can you please put the error in the question?

Comment: Please state your problem clearly for anyone to help you.

Comment: @ruddra I just pasted error.

Comment: @SurajUpadhyay Sorry, this is a Django project. I got this error when I tried to migrate the models.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `db.sqlite3` if you're using built-in django db, and re-run `makemigrations` then `migrate`

Comment: I tried, but still got the same error. At last I started a new project, ran migrations for the models one by one successfully. It seems the error is from the file of clinics.0001_initial.py. I modified the model file after first makemigration but didn't run migrate. When I tried to migrate, all initial.py files inherit 0001_initial.py. So the error persists. I am very strange why no "as_sql" question, only about "to_sql"